Pycharm hovering methods causes a python crash popup on loading documentation
When I hover over some methods in my code (most but not all) I get a 'fetching documentation' popup which is usually followed by a 'Python has stopped working' Windows error. Pycharm nor my program are really affected beyond losing pycharm as my focused window and the documentation not loading. I have simple methods next to each other in a single file where one works and one doesn't. What might cause this?
I've updated and reinstalled pycharm, tried disabling all plugins, and invalidated all caches. That's all made no difference. This project is fairly old and the problem arose suddenly maybe a couple weeks ago.
Using python 3.10

I had the same error on Pycharm 2024.3 EAP and 2024.2.2. Downgrading Pycharm to version 2024.1.6 resolved the issue for me.
